# JNDI issue with Websphere 6 UserTrasaction and Quartz Scheduler

Tags: java, hibernate, websphere, quartz-scheduler, websphere-6

I have my Web Application running on WebSphere 6.0 and also there are some Quartz Scheduler Tasks. If I do the lookup like that in hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<property name="jta.UserTransaction">java:comp/UserTransaction</property>
```

It works fine with my Web Application, but any threads initiated by Quartz Timers fail to access the DB using that lookup string. But if I use

```
<property name="jta.UserTransaction">jta/usertransaction</property>
```

Then it is the opposite. I will get quartz timers working but I can't do the lookup inside my Web Application.

Is there any way to make them both work with same hibernate configuration?

EDT: here is my quartz.properties file. By the way Quartz Version is 1.5.2.

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = TestScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = one


org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount =  5
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 4

org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 5000

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
```

Comment: Can you also post your Quartz config so we can help you?

Comment: quartz.properties file?

Comment: Quartz is not recommended scheduling solution in WAS.

Comment: Even if it is I can't do anything about it. It was implemented long time ago and it works. We don't have time and money to do the full refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is relevant to you but I recently had a similar problem. My issue was remote and local access and altering my design a bit and adding the interface names to my @Local & @Remote annotations worked for me.

Comment: I think it's not relevant since there is no EJBs used in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss the transaction management in your quartz.properties.
Something like this:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.userTransactionURL=jta/usertransaction
org.quartz.scheduler.wrapJobExecutionInUserTransaction=true
```

The idea is to tell Quartz to wrap the job execution in a transaction and where to get it.